# php mysql_query use variable as field name

Tags: php, mysql

I know that i shouldn't use mysql_query for make database query, but i need to modify an existing code.
What i need to do is to pass a php variable as field name of sql query. 
I've try in this way:

```
$my_field = "field_name";
mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET ".$my_field." =somevalue") or die(mysql_error());
```

but i've noticed that it's wrong, because resulting query is

```
UPDATE my_table SET  =somevalue
```

What's the correct way to do it?

Comment: Could be because of a syntax error - you're missing a closing `"` after `=somevalue`

Comment: Can you post us the error thrown. Use error_reporting. If you are getting a blank page, then you got some syntax error in previous lines.

Answer (score 0):

you missed the closing quotes, change to:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE my_table SET ".$my_field." =somevalue") or die(mysql_error());
```

for checking, add the statement to variable and echo it, as:

```
$my_field = "field_name";
$query = "UPDATE my_table SET ".$my_field." =somevalue");
echo $query; //see the output to check if it shows correct statement
```

Comment: it was only a copy error, i have quotes (i've edited my question too)

Comment: @giozh well apart from that there does not seem to be any issue with your code you've posted that could lead to such output..

Comment: it's strange also for me, but i still have this problem

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$my_field = "my_field";
$my_value = "my_value;
$query = "UPDATE my_table SET $my_field=$my_value");
```

php allows variables to work inside double quotes